# Получить все возможные значения из БД

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть система файлов и папок.
В данном контексте - папка и файл некое структурированное значение в БД.
Я хочу сделать удаление папки. Для этого мне нужно узнать все ID файлов и папок, которые могут находится внутри удаляемой папки.

Моя таблица folders:

id folder_id
1  0

Моя таблица files

id folder_id
1  0

Например папка folder_id 90 может находится в folder_id 100, а та в свою очередь может находится в десятках других.

Как мне получить все связанные таким образом значения из таблицы mySQL методами php ?

Comment: это можно получить и без пхп. версия mysql то какая

Comment: буду благодарен за любой путь, примерную схему или подсказку. Версия 5.7.26-29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов хранения иерархических структур в БД:

- **Adjacency List («список смежности»)** Для каждой записи хранится id родителя. Вся ветка вычисляется рекурсивными запросами. Подходит для небольшой вложенности. Требуется много запросов к бд
- **Materialized Path («материализованный путь»)** В каждой записи хранится длинная строка, содержащая все id родителей с неким разделителем
- **Nested Sets («вложенные множества»)** В каждой записи хранится пара колонок lft и rgt, хранящие диапазон всех вложенных элементов. Можно быстро получить всю ветку, но много накладных расходов на вставку новой записи или перемещение её между ветками.
- **Closure Table («таблица связей»)** В отдельной таблице хранятся все связи родитель-потомок. Быстрое получение нужной ветки, но большое кол-во записей связей. Сложности с выводом отсортированного дерева

Существует множество реализаций данных алгоритмов как в php, так и непосредственно в хранимых процедурах mySQL.

Преимущества и недостатки каждого из способов надо рассматривать вместе с требованиями к конкретному проекту